# Añadir un nuevo usuario de Firebase al instalar el plugin en un proyecto angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, visual-studio, firebase, npm

Tengo un proyecto de angular ya creado, y quiero subirlo al hosting de firebase. El problema viene por que en proyectos anteriores ya realice este paso, pero con en otra cuenta de firebase.

Y ahora al añadir el plugin de firebase mediante el comando `ng add @angular/fire` me aparecen los proyectos de firebase del usuario anterior, y no se como cambiar al usuario que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un 'logout' con 'firebase logout' en la terminal y despues volver hacer un 'firebase login' con otra cuenta.